# React and Django deployment

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx, deployment

I developed an app and I want to deploy it on a server. For backend I use Django and for frontend React. The communication between React and Django is via rest api. I also have an Arduino which communicates with Django via rest. I use nginx on server. What is the best way how to deploy this app? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can use 1 server with nginx and gunicorn and make the axios to point to localhost for the react app, create 1 gunicorn for the django and 2 nginx 1 for the django and the other for the react,

Gunicorn use the socket and service file you can use the below link (it will help you for the deployment of django):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04

for the react app it is easier, you can make the build on your local and clone the project on the server (make the app to point to localhost)

just create nginx file with the belw:

```
server {
   server_name yourdomain.com;
   root /project-path/;
   index index.html index.htm;
   location / {
   try_files $uri /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a server, popular choices to rent one are AWS or Heroku. Both have a free limited trial and tutorials that explain to you how to deploy your project. Heroku should be a easier to use, while AWS provides more features. Links:

-AWS Elastic Beanstalk: https://aws.amazon.com/it/elasticbeanstalk/

-Heroku: https://www.heroku.com

Comment: I already have a VPS with Debian where I host some websites with Nginx. I want host app on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of available alternatives of build and orchestration tools.
For example [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) has many modules for django, nginx, npm, databases... that allow to perform any actions and commands whatever you want. Just configure some [webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) in your repository settings so you could trigger autodeploy by pushing new changes or run it manually if needed.

Answer (score 0):

What i did was use my VPS to host the Django app, and then used graphql (similar to REST) to communicate from React to Django.

The general steps are:

1) on the VPS server, you will have a code directory w/ your Django app, like on your local machine. Just use git to get it there.

2) create a virtualenv on the VPS server with all your needed django/python modules (added via pip) in your code directory

3) create an nginx conf file. i use nginx to proxy_pass to apache, which calls the python app. my nginx listens on port 80, and has a line this this: `proxy_pass http://admin.mysite.com:81;`. Create a link to this config in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and restart nginx.

4) create an apache conf file with `<VirtualHost *:81>` with key lines such as: `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIScriptAlias` which point to your virtual env and your wsgi.py file. make sure to enable this too ('a2ensite`).

5) your project's wsgi.py file will point to your app's settings.

6) restart apache and nginx.

That's the real rough outline, and there are tutorials written. Just search for 'django uwsgi nginx' and that will get your django app running, with the proper endpoints for your react app to call.